# Creating a side-menu using html with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I worked on a side-menu example program. Here the user clicks on the button to display a side menu with various option using html and java script. I have placed my html , js and css files separately, so, that my code looks clean. But on execution it not working properly, whereas when the whole code is placed in single file it works fine. What is the mistake Im making and How to place my code separately in the files so the expected out put is got.

Html:

```
<body>
     <button id="button">Click</button>
     <div id="menu">
     <nav>
        <ul style="list-style-type : none">
            <li> <a href="#" id="close"> Close </a></li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Contacts</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    <script src="sidemenu.js"></script>
```

Js:

```
var getDetails = document.querySelector("#menu");
console.log(getDetails);
var getButton = document.querySelector("#button");
var closeButton = document.querySelector("#close");

getButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    getDetails.addClass('opend');
});

closeButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    getDetails.removeClass('opend');
})
```

css:

```
ul{
   list-style-type: none ;
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to define what "working properly" is...

Comment: are you including the javascript before the html exists?

Comment: yes I have included my js file.

Comment: i mean try putting your script to work on load or after the body, rather than just when it reaches it...

Comment: actually I tried using my script after <body> . I get the expected output but I just want to have my html , js and css file separately

Answer (score 0):

This should be the functionality that you are looking for (assuming that the menu starts as hidden). You are using `addClass` and `removeClass` though and these are not baseline javascript functions. I have changed the js to be pure js to achieve the same result that you wanted though.

```js
var getDetails = document.querySelector("#menu");
console.log(getDetails);
var getButton = document.querySelector("#button");
var closeButton = document.querySelector("#close");

getButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  getDetails.className += 'opend';
});

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  getDetails.className = 'hidden';
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.opend {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="button">Click</button>
  <div id="menu" class="hidden">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" id="close"> Close </a>
        </li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="sidemenu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

addClass and removeClass are jquery functions. They do not work with pure JavaScript.

Add class using add function from JavaScript as:

getDetails.classList.add("opend");

And to remove class using JavaScript:
getDetails.className = "";

If you want to maintain some classes then add them again using add.